# Power BI Bing Maps

Tags: office365, powerbi

I want embed a geographical area in the Bing Maps to show a particular area, and want to use the same in Power BI. Is there any way to do, I already have created an selected area in Bing Map, but didn't find any method to do so, is it possible in power bi Q&A to embed our map.

Answer (score 0):

Piyush,

It's not possible in PowerBI.com, Power BI Designer, and Power View in Excel to use custom geographic regions. In PoserBI.com and Power BI Designer you can use standard Bing geographical reasons - countries, states, cities, and zip codes.  Could you head over to support.powerbi.com and submit your suggestion and provide more information on your scenario. Thanks. -Lukasz

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the functionality is not there out of the box. Having said that, there is very good R integration so you may leverage this component for the custom maps.

Here is a link to the walk through, I have not implemented it personally, but it looks like it may help:

https://dataveld.wordpress.com/2016/02/15/getting-started-with-r-maps-in-microsoft-power-bi/